# Cannot edit outdated answer on locked question

Tags: discussion, editing-help, locked-posts

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012951/708036) to a locked question. Now I didn't realise at first the question was locked and I wanted to edit it so as to show there's a different approach since Java 7.

It hurts my feelings that I cannot edit it or remove it in any way. I don't see why it is worthy to keep such questions / answers...

Any ideas how to edit / remove this?

(This would it be by the way)

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(Paths.get("filename"))) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // handle it
}
```

Comment: You're right, that question should not have been locked, but deleted instead. In addition, I'm not sure your planned edit is in line with the question.

Comment: You're quite right, it is not in line with the question. I would just update the answer to add this version so that people may stop laughing on the old way's ugliness.

Comment: That's one of the old historical questions. It really shouldn't be edited again. In addition, old horrors of ways to do it is what the question was about not new good ones.

Comment: Aside from the specifics of this particular post, shouldn't authors of answers be allowed to edit their own answers for correctness, clarity, and timeliness even if the question is locked?  Why should people who provide answers lose control of their own contributions?

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy valid point. If you'd like you can open up a new question for discussion. I'm sure more people would see.

Comment: @qben:  There are similar questions, but they are immediately downvoted and quickly derailed.  In my conversation with one of the moderators claims that this issue will fall on deaf ears.  So I'm trying hard to not care.