# How to react when significant changes in some technology require new answers or comments to locked questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments, locked-posts

Recently the new release of Python 3.10 introduced a new syntax called `match/case` which is in fact a classical `switch/case` syntax (ref: https://docs.python.org/3.10/whatsnew/3.10.html).

This is crucial from the perspective of the quality of the following very active question: [Replacements for switch statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60208/replacements-for-switch-statement-in-python):

> [image: screen-shot showing the locked question]

The new situation may require new answers (or updating the existing ones) or at least comments below question. For the above example, it's not possible to add a new answer nor comment.

How should we react in such a case? I flagged this question for the moderator intervention but I'd prefer to confirm that this was the right decision.

Comment: You post an answer. No need to drag moderators into it.

Comment: For the general situation, I'd mod flag too, but first, be *very very sure* that the answer you wish to post is *extremely* high quality and not remotely covered by any of the existing answers. When flagging, you might include a link to the Markdown of the answer you wish to post so they can see for themselves if it's worthy.

Comment: @Zoe It's locked.

Comment: There is already [an answer on ``match``/``case`` on that Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30881320/5349916).

Comment: *How to react* ... rage quit ....

Comment: Interestingly the answer that @MisterMiyagi linked was written 6 years ago. Python 3.10 got released last month so I wonder if there have been some changes in that time.

Comment: @Yatin [The author updated it in March](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/30881320/3).

Comment: If there weren't already an updated answer, you can ask a new question specifying the version of Python, linking to the original, noting the differences with the new question, and self-answer it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi that's right, I saw this answer; I tried to ask a general question and look for a generic answer :) However, even for this specific question is probably worth changing the accepted answer (or ask the author of currently accepted for an update)

Comment: Related: [Privileges: edit community wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

Comment: I Am Not A Moderator, and notwithstanding whether an existing answer is relevant in this case: I think flagging is the right course of action. For an active tag such as Python, you can also drop by the [Python chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) – there are many people with better edit privileges, and some mods with background knowledge on the tag frequent the channel. Even if people cannot help you directly, they might advise on how to best formulate a new answer to such a popular question.

Comment: Well, the 5th answer by order of votes already covers the new `match/case` syntax... No reason to bother mods or unlock... If you feel you have some information to add - suggest an edit

Comment: Regarding your last comment above, see [Introducing Outdated Answers project](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405302/6045800)

Comment: Wow, the improved error messages showing missing brackets would have a big effect if people weren't all still using 3.7

Comment: @Nick people rarely read the error messages anyways.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the policy on down voting previously correct but now outdated answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265749/whats-the-policy-on-down-voting-previously-correct-but-now-outdated-answers)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot edit outdated answer on locked question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311002/cannot-edit-outdated-answer-on-locked-question)

Comment: [...and so on...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=outdated+answer)

Comment: @PeterDuniho All of those apply to old outdated answers, not potential new answers ---not that it matters seeing as the answer is already on the post in question---

Comment: @Nick: the third one definitely addresses posting new answers. But more generally, they all actually do, because on Stack Overflow, the way to address outdated answers is to post a new one. There's nothing new in this question; it's all been covered adequately by the hundreds of similar questions posted in the past.

Comment: @PeterDuniho the [third](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311002/cannot-edit-outdated-answer-on-locked-question) is *explicitly* about *editing or removing* a *bad* answer

Comment: @PeterDuniho The fact that this question keeps coming up suggests a pressing need to reevaluate how Stack Overflow works WRT outdated answers, hence the Outdated Answers project. Linking to old questions as dupes, when Outdated Answers has the potential to solve this issue once and for all, is not helpful IMO.

Comment: In general I think that a good way would be to edit all answers not containing match/case and saying that they only reflect knowledge pre Python 3.10 and all answers containing match/case that they don't work pre Python 3.10. It gets tedious, but that's life.

Comment: @IanKemp On the other hand the problem is really not new. Meta talked about outdated answers already in 2015 and maybe even before. The ideas from the past only never got implemented. The problem got worse probably, but I'm not sure if it warrants another discussion. We foremost are limited by speed of change in the platform for many years, not by good ideas of what to change.

Comment: @IanKemp: _"The fact that this question keeps coming up suggests a pressing need to reevaluate how Stack Overflow works WRT outdated answers"_ -- I think you misunderstand how the whole "close as duplicate" thing works. It doesn't matter whether there's a need for a different look; questions that are essentially the same as those asked before are still duplicates, and may still be closed as such. Asking a new question about the same old thing is not helpful.